# JQuery dialogue button color

Tags: jquery

I am not able to change the button color in jquery dialogue box. Please find below my code segment.

```
function TestSelector() {
    $('#popup_dialog').dialog('open');
    $('#popup_dialog').dialog({
        maxHeight: 500,
        width: 150,
        title: 'Test',
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function () {
                if ($('#dc').is(':checked'))
                    dc = "true";
            }
        }
    }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "#dcdcdc");
}
```

Here Button name is "SUBMIT". Please help me out.

Comment: Use like this

$('#popup_dialog').find('.ui-button').addClass('changeColor');

.ui-button.changeColor{
    color: #dcdcdc;
}

Comment: Could you share us your HTML code?

Comment: You have to add the class changeColor in css

Comment: I have added that in CSS but still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works: 
`$('#popup_dialog').find('.ui-button').css('color', 'red'); //set the color as required` 
Optionally define a class and use `.addClass()` instead of `.css()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the class during initialization?

to add class

```
buttons: [ { text: 'Submit', class: 'submitButton' } ]
```

to add style

```
buttons: [ { text: 'Submit', style: 'background:#dcdcdc' } ]
```